# Django forms Decimal field not parsing 0

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am using Django forms in my openstack horizon.

Have created the new form for processing the values for updating a certain details in DB.

Form is for updating the certain values in DB.

So I will enter the values for paid_cost, balance_cost, paid_status and payment_status.

Based on the form values entered that will be updated.

Form field is as follows:

```
invoice_id = forms.CharField(label=_("Invoice ID"),  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}), required=False)
paid_cost = forms.DecimalField(label=_("Paid  Cost"), min_value=0, max_digits=32, decimal_places=2) 
balance_cost = forms.DecimalField(label=_("Balance  Cost"), min_value=0, max_digits=32, decimal_places=2) 
paid_status = (('0', 'New'), ('1', 'Paid'), ('2', 'Declined'), ('3', 'Refunded'))
payment_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=paid_status, required=True )
```

Following is the action for updating the DB.

```
invoice = cloudkitty_conn.reports.update_invoice(invoice_id=data['invoice_id'], payment_status=data['payment_status'], paid_cost=data['paid_cost'], balance_cost=data['balance_cost'])
```

So I am facing the issue here with updating of field such as paid_cost and balance_cost.

Scenario 1 works fine which is as follows:

```
paid_cost = 2.50
balance_cost = 2.25
```

For this sample data it is working fine.

DB value updated as needed.

```
mysql> select * from invoice_details \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 id: 3
          tenant_id: 12fabdf1e7744e91b0a1c3ee511f876d
        tenant_name: demo
         invoice_id: demo-3-2016
         total_cost: 4.75
          paid_cost: 2.50
       balance_cost: 2.25
     payment_status: 0
```

Scenario 2 is not working fine, details were as follows:

```
paid_cost = 4.75
balance_cost = 0.00
```

See after adding this values, DB value for balance_cost not changed:

```
mysql> select * from invoice_details \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 id: 3
          tenant_id: 12fabdf1e7744e91b0a1c3ee511f876d
        tenant_name: demo
         invoice_id: demo-3-2016
         total_cost: 4.75
          paid_cost: 4.75
       balance_cost: 2.25
     payment_status: 0
```

To be more clear issue is occurs when we are entering value as 0 or 0.00.

Someone let me know if there is any issue which is already there regarding this Django forms Else I will check in my code itself for any issues

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve], your question is unclear

Comment: @Sayse Please check now, I think its clear now, I provided necessary details I guess